# WhatsApp audio calls fail to connect

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, calls, connection-issues, nexus-6

I recently bought a second-hand Nexus 6 running Lineage OS 18.1. Everything working great with one exception: WhatsApp reproducibly fails to establish audio calls with the error:

> Couldn't place a call. Make sure your phone has an Internet connection and try again.

I tried it from two WiFi networks, where other phones work without issues, so it cannot be a network-related problem. Also, the Nexus 6 does have an internet connection, even WhatsApp itself can send and receive text messages without problems.

Since Lineage OS is not officially supported, I installed a factory image (Android 7.1.1, the latest available one), installed WhatsApp there as the only app, and gave it all possible permissions, and still the problem occurs.

Interestingly, other messengers like Telegram have no issues placing audio calls, just WhatsApp does (unable to place or receive calls).

I tried to contact WhatsApp support, but:

- Through the WhatsApp chat, I only got some machine-generated replies which didn't solve the issue, then the chat has been closed.
- Through the contact form on their website, I got an email reply, but I couldn't answer the email as the email I sent didn't go through. I received an automated email with

  > 554 5.7.1 POL-P6 Message refused https://www.facebook.com/postmaster/response_codes?ip=209.85.160.45#POL-P6
- I answered via the contact form again, but at some point, the "submit" stopped working. When clicking it, just nothing happens anymore.

So now I'm still here with this problem and don't know what to do next.

Comment: Wild guesses 1.disable VPN /Anti Virus apps 2. Try to make a call from WhatsApp web see if you can now make from mobile app 3. Update the app to latest 4.go to a third party site like apk pure and try earlier versions 5.reboot. Like I said weird guesses

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! 1. There is none, it's a fresh install with WA as only additional app. 2. I could connect WA web but there is no call option (not available under Linux). 3. It's freshly installed, no update is available. 4. I went there but cannot find earlier versions, where can I find them? 5. A reboot didn't help either, unfortunately.

Comment: https://www.apkmirror.com/?post_type=app_release&searchtype=apk&sortby=date&sort=asc&s=Whatsapp

Comment: I tried a rather old version (from 2017) and it told me that the system date is wrong. So I tried a rather recent version (from June 2023) and the calls still don't work. I will try something around 2020 now...

Comment: So, a version from 2021 still said that the system time is too new. A version from 2022 says that it is outdated and requires an update. I fear, this idea won't work out...

Comment: Re: APK, WhatsApp does block outdated versions, so only the last N versions are allowed. However, the "*system date is wrong*" error is kind of interesting since it's similar to how SSL handshake usually fails due to time discrepancies. Does your timezone observe a change in DST?

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, we are in summer time now. But, after testing quite some versions, I can observe that very old ones complain about wrong system time, not so old ones complain about requiring an update and just the rather recent ones actually work (but the issue with audio calls still stays). I got some logs, possibly they are helpful: https://pastebin.com/bXnxADEE I think, the call starts at the time stamp 12:11:45.409.